# VMware tools: vsock and vmhgfs does not work

Tags: linux, vmware-player

I'm trying to install the recent VMware tools in an LFS system (kernel 3.16.2).

First, I compiled the kernel with all vmware stuff enabled, which left only `vmhgf`s to be managed by VMware tools. The installation was successful, but `vmhgfs` and `vmci` components reported failure at startup.

Since `vmci` loads before `vmhgfs`, I decided to fix it first. I removed `vmci` and `vsock` from the kernel and let VMware tools take care of it. After a tiny patch of `vsock` code (`sk_data_ready` issue), I managed to install the tools in this configuration. Now `vmci` loads successfully, but `vsock` fails to load.

Reading system log I found this:

```
Jan 18 04:34:46 titov-lfs vmusr[3345]: [ warning] [vmusr] SOCKET failed to create socket, error 97: Adress family not supported by protocol
Jan 18 04:34:46 titov-lfs vmusr[3345]: [ warning] [vmusr] SimpleSock: Couldn't get VMCI socket family info.
```

When trying to mount shared folder I receive this:

```
root [ ~ ]# mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

I've enabled VMware tools logging, but these logs show nothing interesting.

I'm stuck for now. Any ideas on how to debug and fix this? May be I am missing some important stuff in the kernel?

UPDATE:

I found out that

```
modprobe vsock
modprobe vmhgfs
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

works fine, so the problem lies somewhere in the bootscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to resolve the issue.

I found the way to run VMware tools init script in debug mode. To do this one needs to add

```
VMWARE_DEBUG="yes"
```

in the begining of the script.

After that the problem became evident. The script was calling `/sbin/lsmod` , however LFS installs `lsmod` in `/bin` . A symlink fixed the issue.